# How do I get this MySQL script to work?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get this to work. I just can not find the error.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM vw_Transactions_Users t
 WHERE t.IsDeleted = 0 
   AND t.DateEntered >= '2009-10-21 00:00:00' 
   AND t.DateEntered <= '2014-10-21 00:00:00'
 LIMIT 100 OFFSET 1 + (1-1)*100
```

Comment: what you getting error?

Comment: What's exactly the problem? Your OFFSET would be easily rewritten to `OFFSET 1`, because (1-1)*100 = 0*100 = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `limit` statement takes *constants* as the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) points out:

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be nonnegative integer constants, with these
>   exceptions:

So you fix this with:

```
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 1
```

Or use a prepared statement and do the calculation in the application layer.

Comment: Alright. I will use a prepared statement with parameters. Thank you.